# Linq to XML (C#) parse XML tree with no attributes/id to object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a class (Person) and a XML tree:

```
<rows>
    <row>
        <number>1110</number>
        <name>Street</name>
        <value>First Avenue</value>
        <description>First Avenue</description>
    </row>
    <row>
        <number>1120</number>
        <name>House number</name>
        <value>281</value>
        <description>281</description>
    </row>
    <row>
        <number>1160</number>
        <name>Postal</name>
        <value>2552AD</value>
        <description>2552AD</description>
    </row>
    <row>
        <number>1170</number>
        <name>Area</name>
        <value>Peru</value>
        <description>Peru</description>
    </row>
</rows>
```

The person class has attributes like street, house number, postal, and area. How do I fill this person object?

The problem in my query is that I dont know where to add:

```
where (string)c.Element("name") == "Street"
```

My code thus so far:

```
public class XMLparser
{
    public Person XMLparse(string path)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        List<Person> ListPerson = new List<Person>();
        XDocument file = XDocument.Load(path);
        var query = from c in file.Descendants("row")
                    select new
                    {
                        c.Element("value").Value 
                    };

        // Loop through results
        foreach (var value in query)
        {
            person._street = value.Value;
            person._housenumber = value.Value;
            person._postal = value.Value;
            person._area = value.Value;
        }

        return person;
   }
}
```

What I want is to take from the xml and fill it in

```
person._street = value.Value;      //<-- First Avenue
person._housenumber = value.Value; //<-- 281
person._postal = value.Value;      //<-- 2552AD
person._area = value.Value;        //<-- Peru
```

EDIT:

Here is the original XMl tree.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <results>
      <person>
        <categories>
          <category>
            <number>01</number>
            <name>Person</name>
            <rows>
              <row>
                <number>0110</number>
                <name>ID</name>
                <value>value ID</value>
                <description>value ID</description>
              </row>
            </rows>
          </category>
          <category>
            <number>08</number>
            <name>Address</name>
            <rows>
              <row>
                <number>1110</number>
                <name>Street</name>
                <value>value street</value>
                <description>value street</description>
              </row>
              <row>
                <number>1120</number>
                <name>House number</name>
                <value>value House number</value>
                <description>value House number</description>
              </row>
              <row>
                <number>1160</number>
                <name>Postal</name>
                <value>value Postal</value>
                <description>value Postal</description>
              </row>
              <row>
                <number>1170</number>
                <name>Area</name>
                <value>value Area</value>
                <description>value Area</description>
              </row>
            </rows>
          </category>
        </categories>
      </person>
      <person>
        <categories>
          <category>
            <number>01</number>
            <name>Person</name>
            <rows>
              <row>
                <number>0110</number>
                <name>ID</name>
                <value>value ID</value>
                <description>value ID</description>
              </row>
            </rows>
          </category>
          <category>
            <number>08</number>
            <name>Address</name>
            <rows>
              <row>
                <number>1110</number>
                <name>Street</name>
                <value>value Street</value>
                <description>value Street</description>
              </row>
              <row>
                <number>1120</number>
                <name>House number</name>
                <value>value House number</value>
                <description>value House number</description>
              </row>
              <row>
                <number>1130</number>
                <name>House number extra</name>
                <value>value House number extra</value>
                <description>value House number extra</description>
              </row>
              <row>
                <number>1160</number>
                <name>Postal</name>
                <value>value Postal</value>
                <description>value Postal</description>
              </row>
              <row>
                <number>1170</number>
                <name>Area</name>
                <value>value Area</value>
                <description>value Area</description>
              </row>
            </rows>
          </category>
        </categories>
      </person>
    </results>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
XDocument file = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var persons
  = file.Descendants("rows")
        .Select (x => 
            {
                var person = new Person();
                var values = x.Descendants("row")
                              .GroupBy(y => y.Element("name").Value, 
                                       y => y.Element("value").Value)
                              .ToDictionary (y => y.Key, y => y.First());

                foreach(var value in values)
                {
                    switch (value.Key)
                    {
                        case "Street":
                            person.Street = value.Value;
                            break;
                        case "House number":
                            person.Housenumber = value.Value;
                            break;
                        case "Postal":
                            person.Postal = value.Value;
                            break;
                        case "Area":
                            person.Area = value.Value;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return person;
            });
```

It assumes that the XML can contain multiple `rows` tags, one for each person. It then gets the name and value of each `row` tag inside the `rows` tags and initializes a person with the values.

Comment: Could you expand your post with some details on why you used GroupBy? This code achieves the same thing; var values = x.Descendants("row").ToDictionary(y => y.Element("name").Value, y => y.Element("value").Value); But I'm curious if I've missed some subtle aspect of your answer. Cheers

Comment: @ChrisMcAtackney: Your code throws an exception if there are multiple `row` tags for one property. Mine simply takes the first and ignores all other. Which code to use depends very much on the context: If you can be sure, this situation doesn't arise, use your shorter version, otherwise use mine. The XML looks like it comes from a legacy system and in such cases I tend to be careful.

Comment: Cool, thanks for explaining that. Null-safety in LINQ queries is something I'm still getting to grips with, so it's always useful to pick up tips like this.

Comment: Looks very promising! 

I can't run the code right now (some issues with the laptop). I will give asap a reply in the morning on how it went. But in the meantime a big thank you in advance.
Afterwards I will have to test adding multiple persons, extra Xelement etc etc.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth 
Thank you for the codes. I tried quick watch on var persons and I see the attributes filled. 

However I have trouble understanding your codes (lambda expression (?) part and what if I have multiple persons, where can I add the line "persons.Add(person);"?

In my original post I will add the original XML tree.

Comment: For example, to add the person_ID attribute. I need to select the Xelement value from Xelement person in Xelement category.

Comment: @Danny: In the new XML you provided there is no value element inside person. Which tag exactly specifies the person's ID?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth
Every Person has an ID. The ID is situated in person -> categories -> category (where name=person) -> rows -> row -> value (of name=ID).

Every person must have category one. For example the values in the first XML tree is category 8 (address) but might as well be category 6 (marriage info).

Comment: @Danny: This is getting too far here. Please try to understand what my code does and how LINQ to XML works in general and then adjust the code provided to your specific needs.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth
yeah I will. I tried to do this incrementally. But thank you, at least I have an object filled now :)

EDIT: Do you mind if after trial and error I post a new question with the code you provided? I will add credits.

Answer (score 0):

Your Linq query needs to include both "naam" value and the "value" value. Then in the foreach loop add a switch block with case blocks for each expected "naam" value. Then store the "value" value in the Person object.

Answer (score -1):

The below code should give you a list of person objects:

```
string sampleXml =
            @"<rows>
      <row>
        <number>1110</number>
        <name>Street</name>
        <value>First Avenue</value>
        <description>First Avenue</description>
      </row>
      <row>
        <number>1120</number>
        <name>House number</name>
        <value>281</value>
        <description>281</description>
      </row>
      <row>
        <number>1160</number>
        <name>Postal</name>
        <value>2552AD</value>
        <description>2552AD</description>
      </row>
      <row>
        <number>1170</number>
        <name>Area</name>
        <value>Peru</value>
        <description>Peru</description>
      </row>
    </rows>";
        var file = XDocument.Parse(sampleXml);

        var query = from row in file.Descendants("row")
                    select new Person
                    {
                        Street = row.Element("number").Value,
                        HouseNumber = row.Element("name").Value,
                        Postal = row.Element("value").Value,
                        Area = row.Element("description").Value
                    };

        var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: -1: Did you test it? This is something completely different. Each `row` tag represents one property of the `Person` class. Which property is defined by the value of the `name` tag.